# Как работает оптимизация конвейера процессора на уровне ассемблерных инструкций?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, процессор

Процессор может идти на радикальные меры и пытаться угадать ветку, для оптимизации конвейера. В с++ есть атрибуты как [[luckly]], как они влияют на конечный ассемблер, разве программист может явно повлиять на такие вещи? Это предусмотрено в х86, arm?

Comment: Да, программист может явно влиять на это. Конечно, если такая возможность есть в языке. Да, это предусмотрено в процессорах. У разных процессоров разные команды. [Пример](https://www.1024cores.net/home/in-russian/ram---ne-ram-ili-cache-conscious-data-structures#h.p_ID_216)

Comment: [Cache control instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_control_instruction)

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62222212), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7346929), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1851299), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14332848)